# add and share arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create a `Person` class which has `getName()` method, `addFriend(Person R)` method, `ArrayList<Person> getFriendList()`

```
String Name;
private ArrayList Person friend = new ArrayList Person ();

public Person(String name)
{

this.Name=name;

    }

public ArrayList<Person> getFriendList(){

    return friend;

}


public void addFriend(Person R){

friend.add(R);

}

FriendsOfFriends(){    
    //list of friends of friends of this person.
}

public static int (p,q){    
     //return the number of friends shared by both R and q.
}
```

Comment: Hint: 1/ friends of friends, create an empty list, for-loop over direct friends and for each one add all its friends  to the empty list. 2/ see answer below

Comment: This is not the way SO works, you should at least show what have you tried and why it isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int numberOfMutualFriends(Person p, Person q){
    //return the number of friends shared by both R and q.


    return intersection(p.friend,q.friend).size();

}

public List<Person> intersection(List<Person> list1, List<Person> list2) {
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();

    for (Person t : list1) {
        if(list2.contains(t)) {
            list.add(t);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

You'll need to redefine the `hashCode` and the `equals` method in order to make it work.

Comment: btw, intersection can be easily implemented using [`.retainAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-)

Comment: Thanks @Felip Sulser

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're studying bulk operations on collections.

To get friends of friends, use [`Set#addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) in the for-each loop:

```
 List<Person> getFriendsOfFriends() {
     Set<Person> res = new HashSet<>();  // empty set
     for (Person p : this.friends)       
         res.addAll(p.friends);          // add all p's friends
     return new ArrayList<>(res);        // copy to ArrayList and return
 }
```

To get number of mutual friends, use [`Set#retainAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-):

```
public static int numberOfMutualFriends(Person p, Person q) {
    // set containing friends of p (not to modify p.friends itself)
    Set<Person> res = new HashSet<>(p.friends);  
    res.retainAll(q.friends);            // leave only mutual friends
    return res.size();         
}
```

This will work if there are no `Person` clones in data (i. e. every `Person` is presented as exactly one object). Otherwise, to make it work correctly, you must override `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` in `Person` class.